# BIRT - execute sql query under getDefaultValueList Method of a parameter

Tags: parameters, dataset, birt

I'm wondering if I could use a DataSet or a SQL query in getDefaultValueList method?

I want to do something like shown below, but the below code doesnt work as the datasets are executed after the parameter form is displayed.

```
if (dataSetRow["customerId"] == reportContext.getHttpServletRequest().getParameter("customerId"))
{
  reportContext.getDesignHandle().findParameter("SomeParameter").hidden = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to hide or display `SomeParameter` based on the value of the parameter `customerId`?

Since all parameters are "loaded" into the form at the same time, such a direct connection isn't possible. You could, however, look into cascading parameters and see whether you can adapt your problem to their functionality.